# Where to put the 'return' keyword in java?

Tags: java, return, return-value

Here are the requirements for the task:

- The class should have a constructor that takes two arguments: a string value for the person's name and an integer value for the person's age.
- Create a toString method that returns the name and age of the person. The values ​​must be separated by a space.
- Create the getName methods () and getAge () methods to return the person's name and age.
- Create the growOlder (nYears) method to increase the person's age by nYears (an integer).
- In the growOlder (nYears) method, the value of nYears must be ensured that it is a positive value. At positive value (including the value zero), the person's age should be increased and the method should return the value true (to indicate that the change in value was completed). If the value of nYears is negative, no change in age should occur and the method should return the value false (to indicate that the change in value did not occur).

Note: nYears = 13 is provided for the task
This is what our code will be tested on:
[image]

---

So far I have the following code and it works BUT I am having trouble finalizing it because of the "return" keyword.

```
public class Person{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int getOlder;

    public Person(){
        this("Otto", 25);
    }
    public Person( String name, int age ){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }
    public int growOlder(int nYears){

        if(nYears >= 0){
            age = age + 13;
            System.out.println("true");

        }else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }
       return nYears; //ERROR
    }

    public String toString( ){
        return getName() + " " + getAge();

    }
}
```

I am supposed to get results like:

```
Otto 25
true
Otto 38
false
Otto 38
```

But with this code, I get these results:

```
Otto 25
true
13
Otto 38
false
-13
Otto 38
```

If I don't place a return or return value, it creates an error. I dont really know what to do here. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to `return age;` instead of `return nYears;`?

Comment: Why do you always add 13 to `age` and what is the purpose of `private int getOlder;`?

Comment: just change the getOlder's method return value to void and remove the statement "return nYears;"

Comment: Your code is incomplete; there is no code that Indonesia y of your methods.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt "*... Indonesia y ...*" - uhm... Thailand x? :)

Comment: @Turing85 thanks - the iPhone autocomplete gets more creative every day. I meant to say "no code that invokes any of your methods".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, there are pieces of code called methods. (Methods are sometimes referred to as functions.)

In this code snippet you have defined a method:

```
public int growOlder(int nYears){
    if(nYears >= 0){
        age = age + 13;
        System.out.println("true");

    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }
   return nYears; //ERROR
}
```

The method is **public**ly accessible from code outside the class.

The method **return**s a value of type **int**.

The method is called **growOlder**.

The method accepts a variable of type **int** declared as **nYears**.

So methods are defined the following way:

```
<visibility> <return type> <name>    <parameters>
   public         int     growOlder  (int nYears)
```

The return statement is used to exit a method. When a method is defined with a return type (anything other than void), it's mandatory for all code paths in the method to have a return statement along with the value it's returning.

Let's take a look at your method again and see how to make the output work as you wish.

```
   public int growOlder(int nYears){

        if(nYears >= 0){
            age = age + 13;
            System.out.println("true");

        }else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }
       return nYears; //ERROR
    }
```

It looks as if you are printing true and false instead of returning it.

The action here is to change the return type from **int** to **boolean**, and replace your `System.out.println()` with `return true` and `return false`.

After this change, we can condense the method to communicate our message more clearly:

```
public boolean growOlder(int nYears){
    age += nYears; //Add nYears to age and update its value
    return nYears >= 0; //Return the value of the expression "is nYears greater than or equal to 0" yes results in true, no results in false.
}
```

Comment: but if do so, it creates an error saying "error: 'void' type not allowed here
System.out.println( person.growOlder( 13 ) ); and  error: 'void' type not allowed here
System.out.println( person.growOlder( -13 ) );

Comment: That's because the System.out.println method you are using accepts a value. As you can see when you make your growOlder method void, it no longer returns a value. Grow the person older then you can get the new age using person.getAge() and give this value to the System.out.println method.

Comment: Sorry, I have just noticed your edit with "test". Are they requiring that specific test code in particular?

Comment: I hope my answer helps you understand the usage of the "return" keyword.

Comment: Yes, thats what theyre using to test my code. And yes, your answer does help me understand the usage of "return". Thank you! but it still doesnt work on my code somehow

Comment: Yes, now I see you have mixed up return and printing to the screen. Your code shouldn't have System.out.println , only the test code should.

Comment: I edited my answer to accommodate the solution to your problem

Comment: IT WOOOORKED!!!! Thank you :D I will now be posting the correct version of the code for clarity

Comment: Hang on, Ill post a version as well, I just wanted you to figure it out on your own first for practice :)

Comment: alright, thank you again! have a nice day/afternoon/evening :)

Comment: Okay I updated the answer with an example code. I hope your Java learning goes well. :)

Comment: Methods and functions are similar, but they're not one and the same. Methods are associated with objects, functions are not. Java only has methods because everything is organized into classes. The closet you can get to a function is a static method.